# Javascript - Security for showing/hiding content if a user has paid to upgrade

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend, web-frontend

So I have a web application where I call my user api to check if a user has upgraded and I get returned a JSON object with `subscribed` being the variable that tracks whether a user has upgraded.

Now, if the user has upgraded the object returns `subscribed: true` so what I'm currently doing to show/hide content is:

```
if(subscribed === true) {
    $(".content").show();
} else {
    $(".content").remove();
}
```

so to me this seems really sketchy since javascript is a client side language and I feel that a user could very easily manipulate either the `subscribed` variable or the `.remove()` function...

My question is, is this a safe way of going about this? Is there a better way?

Comment: Why not check to see if the user has subscribed on the server side?  If they haven't, suppress the function that emits the restricted content.

Comment: @JohnWu I can't use a server side language because this is a chrome extension :/

Comment: There is no such thing as client side security. If they don't have the right to see it, you don't send it.

Comment: @Katie If you can't use a server side language, what program is responding to the JSON request that checks for the subscription?

Comment: @Bindrid sorry I forgot to mention this is a chrome extension so I don't have access to the server side.

Comment: @JohnWu Google's In-App purchase (https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/payments-iap)

Comment: Nothing is safe in javascript

Comment: As we are all telling, the only way to keep non subscribers from seeing it is not to send it.  And a simple  subscribed == true will not keep content protected.  Users, specially hackers and developers, have full control of any content sent to the web.